# How to choose the right loss function

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am currently working on a deep science Xi project for fire spread prediction, the dataset used is next_day_wildfire_spread, including elevation information, weather, vegetation and other information, the label is a 64x64 fire mask matrix, there are three values (-1 means uncertain, 0 means no fire, 1 means there is a fire), what loss function should I use for this task? What does the evaluation function choose?

The loss functions I have tried so far include Dice coefficient and cross-entropy loss function, but the results are not very good, and the evaluation function is AUC, which also does not achieve good results

Comment: Hi 吴一凡, in order for people to answer, you should include some more details in your question, for example: what this 2D matrix actually represents (a land surface? 64x64 means 64x64 unit surfaces?), what is your deep learning model (at least the category it belongs to), what you have tried so far (most importantly, dataset dimension)

Answer (score 0):

The choice of a loss function depends upon many factors, which may or may not be related to the network architecture, the training dataset, output features, etc.. But here there are some general guidelines.

Your task can be interpreted as a binary/ternary segmentation task, where you are interested in two labels (Fire, No Fire) and possibly having a third label that express uncertainty (Maybe Fire). Usually, people ask their neural models  to give a continuous output with F/NF as extreme values; this means that when the output is in the middle, it can be interpreted as uncertainty. By interpreting your segmentation problem this way, it becomes easier for the network to understand the task. Plus, it is generally easier to train a network for just two classes (even if you will infer three classes).

Dice-Soresen it is usually a good similarity index in many binary segmentation tasks, *when the is no class imbalance* (i.e., the number of F and NF is relatively similar - if not the case, I'd suggest you to go for a more general interpretation of the Dice-Soresen loss which is the Tversky Loss). There are ways to use the Dice-Soresen score for multi-label segmentation tasks, but that means that you should properly handle the way it is calculated.

Dice-Soresen and entropy won't help in case you want to exploit some features of the labels, for example the spatial correlation between adjacent land-elements (e.g. you are fine if your neural model finds a F near a true F). In that case, you may want to have a look for loss functions that are more suited for what you actually need from your neural model to do (A review of recent segmentation metrics can be found [here](https://github.com/Visceral-Project/EvaluateSegmentation), which can give you some idea about what you would like to implement)